# React router doesn't render route, but path variables are set

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was trying to use my React router to render a companent based on the path in the browser. The path gets set correctly and the {this.props.location} object returns the right path. yet my router doesn't seem to be working.

Router file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Infopage from './setSubscriptionPage';
import TrialRequestForm from './trialRequestForm';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class SubscriptionActions extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.location);
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                make a decission
                <Router history={history}>
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path='/trial' Component={TrialRequestForm} />
                        <Route exact path='/teams' Component={Infopage} />
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default SubscriptionActions;
```

browser: 
[image]

any hints would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here,

```
<Route exact path='/trial' Component={TrialRequestForm} />
```

You wrote `Component` with capital `C` which should be `component` small `c`.

```
<Route exact path='/trial' component={TrialRequestForm} />
```